# Key Press Event In Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many input types in the form .Now i want that the user can enter only integer values in the input types.The input can be like this **110.00** only two values after **.**.But i am not able to get this features.

I have done with the interger input but i am not getting how can we do this :
**Code**

```
$(".amount_class").live("keypress",function(e){
        var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        var Enteted = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
        if ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || charCode == 8 || charCode == 9 || charCode == 37 || charCode == 39 || (charCode == 46 && Enteted != '.'))
            return true;
        else
        return false;
    });
```

The values are amount and it can be decimal but not more than two after decimal sign.Please help me

Comment: `.live` is deprecated. Use `.on` instead. Also it's better to listen `keyup` event instead of `keypress`

Comment: but how could i match 110.00 ??

Comment: You can use this plugin, I use it, it's lightweight and efficient : http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Comment: I would suggest a native javascript solution but since you are using jQuery take a look @ [`autoNumeric`](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) plugin

Comment: take a look http://jsfiddle.net/3Ckw2/71/

Comment: The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input. http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: Don’t suppress the default browser behavior when the ENTER key is pressed, because otherwise the change event won’t be fired. Key code of ENTER is 13.

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel when you already have a plugin which works flawlessly. see this http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/ autoNumeric plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this and working fine for me :

```
$('.salary').live("keypress",function(e) {
        var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        var Enteted = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
        if(!((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || charCode == 8 || charCode == 9 || (charCode == 37 && Enteted !='%') || charCode == 39 || charCode == 46)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } 

        if(charCode == 46 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1 && Enteted ==".") {
            e.preventDefault();
        } // prevent if already dot
        if(charCode == 46  && Enteted =="." && !$(this).val()) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } 
        if($(this).val().indexOf('.')!=-1){
            if($(this).val().split(".")[1].length >= 2){ 
                 if(charCode != 8  && charCode != 46) e.preventDefault();
                if( isNaN( parseFloat( this.value ) ) ) return;
                this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
            }  
         }            
         return this;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use as below

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="checkDecimal" class="decimal" />
```

JS

```
$(function () {
     $('#checkDecimal').bind('paste', function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})+$/.test($(self).val())) $(self).val('');
        }, 0);
    });

    $('#checkDecimal').keypress(function (e) {
        var character = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
        var newValue = this.value + character;
        if (isNaN(newValue) || parseFloat(newValue) * 100 % 1 > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Gaurav will [this](http://blog.crowdint.com/2013/02/27/how-to-limit-two-decimal-digits-in-a-jquery-input-field.html) help you out

Comment: @ankur-singhal it is allwoing user to input all keys i want very specific only intger and single decimal after that only two values like 100.00

Answer (score 1):

have a look here.

**Regex** - `/^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/g;`

i have experimented [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_lib_jquery)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#input_field').keyup(function(e) {
    var regex = /^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/g;
    if (!regex.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = '';

    }
});
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type= "text" id = "input_field" name ="input_field" value=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is every time a user entering a number you have to check two things.

1. Has the user entered decimal point?
2. Are the decimal places more than two?

For the first one you can use `$(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1`
For the second one you can use `$(this).val().substring($(this).val().indexOf('.'), $(this).val().indexOf('.').length).length > 2`

Here is the code:

```
$('.amount_class').keypress(function (event) {
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    var text = $(this).val();

    if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) && (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

And the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VRa6n/959/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use
 value.toFixed(2); 
thats it..